# javascript setInterval fades the same image over and over rather than the next

Tags: javascript, jquery

(edit)
 It is supposed to rotate the fade between 3 images every 5 seconds. But rather it just fades the same one over and over every 5 seconds, never going to the next image. Here's mote context because maybe the error wasn't caused by anything in the initial post:

```
                $(".paging").show();  

                $(".paging a:first").addClass("active"); 

                $(".image_reel img:first").addClass("active");




                var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
                var imageSum = $(".image_reel div").size();  
                var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;



                //Adjust the image reel to its new size
                $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});  


                //Paging  and Slider Function
                rotate = function(){


                    var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
                    var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

                    $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class

                    $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

                    //Slider Animation
                    $(".image_reel").animate({
                        left: -image_reelPosition
                    }, 500 );

                    $(".image_text").animate({
                        left: -image_reelPosition
                    }, 500 );
                }; 
                //Below is part not working right
                fadeImg = function(){

                    $("#group1 img").removeClass('active'); 
                    $next.addClass('active');               

                    $("#group1 img").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 500 );

                    $next.animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 500 );



                };

                //Rotation  and Timing Event
                rotateSwitch = function(){
                    play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 7 seconds
                        $active = $('.paging a.active').next(); //Move to the next paging
                        if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                            $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
                        }
                        rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
                    }, 15000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (7 seconds)

                    playFade = setInterval(function(){ 

                        $next = $(".image_reel img.active").next();
                        if($next.length === 0){
                            $next = $(".image_reel img:first");
                        } 
                        fadeImg();
                    }, 5000);
                };

                rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

                //On Hover
                $(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
                    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
                }, function() {
                    rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation timer
                }); 

                //On Click
                $(".paging a").click(function() {
                    $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
                    //Reset Timer
                    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
                    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
                    rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation timer
                    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
                });
```

markup:

```
<div class="image_reel"> 
    <div id="group1">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/reel_1.png" class="first" /></a>  
        <a href="#"><img src="images/reel_1b.png" class="second" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/reel_1c.png" class="third" /></a>

        <p class="first">  A</p>
        <p class="second">  B</p>
        <p class="third">C</p>

        <div class="slidernav">
            <a href="#first"> A</a> 
            <a href="#second"> B</a> 
            <a href="#third"> C</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

Note that I am aware of plugins to create fade effects, but I'm trying to do it manually for now. Thanks for any response.

Comment: At what relativistic speed are you moving at that 15000 milliseconds == 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that: `$next = $(".image_reel img.active").next();` does not do what you are wanting it to do.  What that is doing is finding `img.active` and then trying to find its next sibling, since it doesn't have any siblings `$next` gets set to an empty jQuery object.

What you want is something like this:

`$next = $(".image_reel img.active").parent().next().find('img');`

Comment: Thanks, something so obvious just didn't click at the time.